# How to use "threat" and" the body health" together?

Tags: collocations

Have I correctly written this sentence? How do I join the negation of "threat" and the phrase "body health" (to say that a threat to body health won't exist)?

> In this way  no  threat to athlete's health will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not use *BE* as a bare intransitive meaning "exist"; *BE* must take a complement. To express what you intend you must use the "existential construction" *there BE*:

> In this way **there will be** no threat to the athlete's health.